# Can I create a legend of a map that I had get from a WMS?

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, legend

Can I create a legend of a map that I had get from a WMS?
Can I create a legend of a raster map with Qgis version 1.7.4, or only with the 1.8 version?

Comment: I can't achieve this either.

Answer (score 4):

QGIS does not use the WMS supplied legend images yet. If you need them for your print layout, you have to download them separately and add them as an image.